# VBA Range Syntax Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a range to ultimately use in a concatinate function, but I'm having some unknown errors. I have attached my entire code, but the error appears to be during the 'myRange' section. The goal of the code is to divide the steps of a process into 360 minute shifts, and then list all of the parts and tools required (found in column H). Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim duration As Integer, n As Long, i As Integer, x As Integer, m As Integer
Dim myRange As Range

n = 3
m = 3
duration = 0
x = 0

For i = 1 To 50

    duration = 0

    While duration < 360

        x = Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(n, "F").Value
        duration = duration + x
        n = n + 1

    Wend

    myRange = Range(Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(m, "H"), Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(n, "H"))
    Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(1, i).Value = ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(myRange)
    m = n

Next i

End Sub

Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As String


    Dim finalValue As String

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
    finalValue = finalValue + CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell

    ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
End Function
```

Comment: Try block-indenting your code so as to make it readable.

Comment: Which worksheet is active when you run this code? Does it work if you make the "SR060-SR070" worksheet active before you run the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problemmatic:

```
myRange = Range(Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(m, "H"), _
                Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(n, "H"))
```

The `Range()` method here has no worksheet qualifier, so it will default to the active worksheet, which - if it's not "SR060-SR070" - will raise an error because your `Cells()` calls are referencing a different sheet.

This would be better as:

```
With Worksheets("SR060-SR070")
    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(m, "H"), .Cells(n, "H"))
End With
```

(and adding `Set` as pointed out by ChipsLetten)

Answer (score 1):

When setting an object variable (range, worksheet or workbook for instance) to refer to an object you must use the `Set` keyword.

```
Set myRange = Range(Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(m, "H"), Worksheets("SR060-SR070").Cells(n, "H"))
```

This is ok because because you are setting the `Value` of the range:

```
Worksheets("Shifts").Cells(1, i).Value = ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(myRange)
```

In your `ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange` function, the `For Each cell ... Next cell` is fine. You should use the `&` operator for joining strings though.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still receiving an issue with the 'Set' line. It says "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: @ChristianGatmaitan: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger? Have you examined the intermediate object of the right-hand expression using the Immediate Window and the Watch Window? What are the results of that?

Comment: What are the values of `m` and `n` variables when you get that error?